# SendGrid - Owin Identity Email Authentication

Tags: c#, smtp, identity, owin, sendgrid

I am having a hard time implementing the Owin Identity 2.0 Authentication via Email.

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code which I use for the smtp client configuration.

### IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Credentials:
        string sendGridUserName = "HansMuster456";
        string sentFrom = "OwinIdentityTest@TestDomain.ch";
        string sendGridPassword = "xxxxx";

        // Configure the client
        var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587);

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        // Create the credentials:
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sendGridUserName, sendGridPassword);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        // Create the message:
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        // Send:
        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
}
```

### SMTP-Log

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6456] Socket#53556591::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#42931033)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6456] Exiting Socket#53556591::EndReceive()    -> Int32#32
System.Net Error: 0 : [6456] Decrypt failed with error 0X90317.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6456] Socket#53556591::Dispose()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6456] SmtpPooledStream::Dispose #49538252
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6456] Exiting SmtpPooledStream::Dispose #49538252
```

Link for the full log file : http://pastebin.com/3ph3PmSM

Answer (score 1):

Remove client.EnableSsl = true; part from your code and check that. it should work.

I have tested this with 'mail.authsmtp.com' and it works fine, you just need to remove client.EnableSsl = true; part as following code.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Credentials:
        string sendGridUserName = "HansMuster456";
        string sentFrom = "OwinIdentityTest@TestDomain.ch";
        string sendGridPassword = "xxxxx";

        // Configure the client
        var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587);

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        // Create the credentials:
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sendGridUserName, sendGridPassword);

        //client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        // Create the message:
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        // Send:
        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
}
```